# How to reference elements in a multi-dict within a list comprehension statement

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, list-comprehension

I could not find an answer to this when googling through the archives (feel like this question should have been asked before).

I am running a hugging face pipeline on top of a pandas dataframe. The structure of my dataframe is simply two columns:

| index | text |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Here is some text |
| 1 | Here is another text |

For each value in `text`, the pipeline (we'll call it `model_func`) runs on that value and returns a multidict for each value e.g. `model_func(df.text.values[0])` returns...

```
{var1:[1,2,3], var2:[4,5,6], var3:[7,8,9]}
```

I want to run this function for all values in `df.text` and assign the outputted `var1,var2` key/values in the dictionary as columns in the original dataframe e.g.

| index | text | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Here is some text | [1,2,3] | [4,5,6] |
| 1 | Here is another text | [7,8,9] | [10,11,12] |

My current (non-working) list comprehension statement attempting to do the above looks like this:

```
df[['var1','var2']] = [model_func(x)['var1','var2'] for x in (df['text'])]
```

Essentially, I want to:

1. Access the first two keys in the returned multidict (and their respective values) returned from model_func.
2. Assign these values to each obs(row) as columns in the original dataframe.

(I'll then use the explode function to expand the respective lists into a long data format so as not to have lists within a pandas series).

I realize this is a bit messy. I would think there has to be a more efficient method for this so am all ears on that end. For now though, the main question I have is quite basic:

How do I reference those two multi-dict keys within a list comprehension (assigning a single key / values pair works e.g. - `df['var1'] = [data_analysis_func(x)['var1'] for x in (df['text'])]` - but not multiple key / values pairs as attempted in the first list comprehension code block above).

Comment: What is the original DataFrame? From what is shown here, it is impossible to help.

Comment: Hey it's a bit messy but just added the data structure. Appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method for this, which simply maps a function to a column (or row) of a DataFrame. In your case, this could be a custom lambda function, for instance:

```
df[["var1","var2"]] = df.apply(lambda row: 
    (
        [row["text"].count("a"), row["text"].count("e"), row["text"].count("i")],
        [row["text"].count("h"), row["text"].count("i"), row["text"].count("t")]
    )
, axis=1)
```

which results in

```
                   text       var1       var2
0     Here is some text  [0, 4, 1]  [1, 4, 1]
1  Here is another text  [0, 1, 2]  [1, 1, 3]
```

Some clarification:

- The `axis=1` specifies that you want to apply it to columns
- You can assign multiple columns like this, but make sure that you return data in the appropriate dimension. Here: The lamba function returns a tuple that holds two lists - the first list for `var1`, the second for `var2`.